# Delaying JQuery; co-ordinating when lines are done?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have a simple script which changes an image into another, waits a bit, and then changes back to the original image. In theory, at least. I'm finding it difficult to time things correctly, plus it doesn't seem to display the second image.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#blah').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('input[name="c"]').fadeOut(250);
        $('input[name="c"]').delay(250).attr("src", 'http://i.imgur.com/vas3I1w.png');
        $('input[name="c"]').fadeIn(250);
        $('input[name="c"]').delay(4000).fadeOut(250);
        $('input[name="c"]').delay(250).attr("src", 'http://i.imgur.com/oNGYocF.png');
        $('input[name="c"]').fadeIn(250);
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="blah">
  <input type="image" src="http://i.imgur.com/oNGYocF.png" alt="" name="c" id="clickme" />
</form>
```

The gist of what I'm trying to accomplish is:

- on click, the image takes 250ms to fade out
- after fading out, change the src to the new image
- take 250ms to fade in
- display the new image for 4s
- take 250ms to fade out
- after fading out, change the src to the original image
- take 250ms to fade in

What am I doing wrong here? It seems like it's skipping the second image entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better using Opacity animation as you don't lose the block element width and height like you do with `$.fadeOut()` here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#blah').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('input[name="c"]').animate({
           opacity:0
        },250, function() {
           $(this).attr("src", 'http://i.imgur.com/vas3I1w.png')
           $('input[name="c"]').animate({
               opacity:1
            },250, function() {
               //then reverse the logic here.
            });
        });
      });
    });
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/3eushzkL/

Note that I've also "preloaded" the images at the top so you don't get a loading delay on the new imagery being put in place.

Comment: Neat. You mentioned `.delay()` stinks, but I would still need some way to delay here, what are you suggested alternatives?

Comment: You could use the "native" callbacks within the animate function or `setTimeout()` - I think a lot of people on SO are a bit hesitant to use `setTimeout()` but if utilised correctly (google it!) it's better and more extensible than jQuery's `delay()`. But I guess it's personal preference really :)

Answer (score 2):

You delay statements must be absolute, so:

```
$('input[name="c"]').fadeOut(250);
$('input[name="c"]').delay(250).attr("src", 'http://i.imgur.com/vas3I1w.png');
$('input[name="c"]').delay(250).fadeIn(250);
$('input[name="c"]').delay(4500).fadeOut(250);
$('input[name="c"]').delay(4750).attr("src", 'http://i.imgur.com/oNGYocF.png');
$('input[name="c"]').delay(4750).fadeIn(250);
```

Or, I suppose you could chain them all together like:

```
$('input[name="c"]')
    .fadeOut(250)
    .delay(250)
    .attr("src", 'http://i.imgur.com/vas3I1w.png')
    .fadeIn(250)
    .delay(4000)
    .fadeOut(250) //etc
```

---

You don't see the second image because these two statements cancel eachother out:

```
$('input[name="c"]').delay(250).attr("src", 'http://i.imgur.com/vas3I1w.png');
$('input[name="c"]').delay(250).attr("src", 'http://i.imgur.com/oNGYocF.png');
```

They both wait 250ms and then change the `src`, the last one wins (which is the original image).

Comment: This answer explains better than mine :(

Comment: @BarrieReader Is the opacity/block element thing still relevant?

Comment: I believe so, if you have text under the button and fade it out using `fadeOut()` then the text jumps up where the element disapears...

Comment: If yo want to keep the space you can use `fadeTo()` i think is the same than opacity.